# Google Apps Script restricted scopes

Tags: google-apps-script

I received the below email from Google.  I have several Google Apps scripts in my Google Drive, that only I use, and run automatically overnight to process CSV reports received in gmail into something meaningful and then email them out to my colleagues.

It is not clear from this email, or the FAQ, whether I now need to do anything to keep them running after the end of March.  I don't THINK I do, but if someone could confirm that would be great.

thanks

> Hi Google API Developer,
>
> We sent this email because you’re listed as a contact on the following
>   Google Cloud Project(s) using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs:
>
> project-id-3665913030667953527 project-id-4131782174672495334 In
>   October 2018, we announced that, in January 2019, new Gmail API
>   policies for restricted scopes will go into effect. We want to let you
>   know that, starting today, you can submit your app(s) that use
>   restricted scopes for verification. Please review the full policy and
>   OAuth FAQ for more information including the secure handling
>   requirement.
>
> What you need to do If you want to use one of the restricted scopes,
>   for verification through the Google API Console (On the left side menu
>   click Credentials, then click OAuth consent screen) between January
>   16th and February 15th, 2019 for the project(s) listed above. Owners
>   and editors of the project will be able to submit for verification and
>   developers with internal apps for users in the same G Suite domain do
>   not need to do this.
>
> If you do not take action If you do not submit for verification by
>   February 15th, 2019, we’ll disable account access for new users on
>   February 22nd, 2019.
>
> If you do not submit for verification by March 31st, 2019, we’ll
>   revoke existing consumer grants.
>
> Thanks, Google Cloud Platform/API Trust & Safety

Comment: The list of restricted scopes is at: [https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en)  For anyone who is trying to determine which of their scopes might be restricted.

Answer (score 1):

Their email is not totally clear, is it? Since you are using the restricted scopes for internal use, you probably don't need to submit your app for verification. However, Google's email says that your access will be revoked after March 31.

You might be getting this email from Google because your app is not listed as an "Internal" Application type. Open your Google developer console to the [OAuth consent screen](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent) settings and check that it is so that Google knows that you don't intend to request access from strangers. See image below.

Don't forget to save your settings after making any changes.

[image: OAuth consent screen settings for Internal usage only]

Comment: That only applies to GSuite accounts ([Basic, Business and Enterprise](https://gsuite.google.com/pricing.html)) where users are part of an organization's domain. For consumer accounts, there is no "internal" option for deploying ones scripts. However, GAS Web Apps can be deployed to be strictly accessible by a single user account and execute only under that account - effectively making the web app private - and this can be done using a consumer account. Google has yet to provide any clarity for that use case.

Comment: @DimuDesigns You're making sense. And I confirmed it with my Gmail account.

Comment: That option isn't available for my scripts.

Comment: @CFO As Dimu Designs pointed out, I am using a GSuite account. You must be using a personal Gmail account. I would suggest that you submit your OAuth app for verification from Google and let them decided whether you need verification based on your use case.

Comment: How? I don't have a homepage or privacy policy, so the form does not allow me to submit the app for verification.  Google Help tells me to use stackoverflow if I need support, but clearly the do not monitor it.