# OAuth2 consent screen warning - verification required by google for scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request

Tags: google-apps-script, blogger

I have build an app script project for posting to blogger with OAuth2 authorization.
I fetch content from some links via UrlFetchApp service which requires https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request scope. I have added the required scopes to manifest.
On google developers console, when I create credentials and add scopes to the OAuth consent screen, it shows me a warning for scope script.external_request, which is
[image]

For trial I had created similar environment which I use as development environment now. I had created it in Oct 2018. I didn't get any such warning for script.external_request scope that time. It was readily added to the OAuth consent screen.

So the question is,
I'm going to use the app script privately forever, still do I really require verification by Google as the warning suggests? Is there any other way out?

Comment: Duplicate.  See this unresolved question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233133/google-apps-script-restricted-scopes/54246071#54246071

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.